Don't receive anything from my tayga in my aws vpc
I have a server at home with both IPv6 and IPv4 addresses. However, my internet provider uses CGNAT, which makes direct connection via IPv4 impossible. To work around this, I created a VPC (with ubuntu) in AWS to set up a NAT64 with Tayga.
Here is how I have configured tayga.
Everything looks fine, but when I try to make a request from an IPv4 network to my server through my VPC, I don't receive anything, even though it seems that my VPC is sending the request to my server.
tshark screenshot
Here is what I have checked so far:
Router rules
AWS routing tables
AWS Network ACLs (inbound/outbound rules)
AWS security group rules
I can connect to my server from the outside using its IPv6 address and also from within my VPC.
What I am expecting to achieve:
I want to connect to my server using an IPv4 address from any IPv4 network. The connection should be routed through the VPC in AWS, which uses NAT64 to translate IPv4 requests to IPv6 for my server.
Any suggestions on what I might be missing?
